# How to manipulate the y-axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I am displaying a ratio in matplotlib with

```
plt.plot(datax, datay, style, color=colour)
```

However, I want the data below `1` to be displayed as `2-1/y`. For example: A data point with the value `2` should be displayed at `2`, a value `1` at `1` but a value `1/2` should be displayed where `0` would be, a value of `1/3` where `-1` would be, `1/4` at `-2` and so forth. However, I want the labels to show the actual value of the data point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you use scatter plot and `datay` is a numpy array, you can build another array of new Y coordinates:

```
datay1 = np.where(datay < 1, 2 - 1 / datay, datay)
```

And then plot the data points in the new positions, but annotate them with old labels:

```
plt.scatter(datax, datay1)
for x,y,y1 in zip(datax, datay, datay1):
    plt.annotate("%.f" % y, xy=(x,y1))
```